# Prove that $k \cdot |I| \leq |\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i|$ for each $I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let ${\cal X} = (X_1,...,X_n)$ be family of subsets and integer $k > 0$. I know that $|\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i| \geq |I|$ for each $I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$. Moreover, $$k \cdot (\min_{I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}} (|\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i|)) \leq |\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i|, \forall I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$$

How can to show that $k \cdot |I| \leq |\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i|$ for each $I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\left|\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\right|\ge|I|$ for each $I\subseteq[n]$, we know that $|X_i|\ge 1$ for each $i\in I$.

Let $I_0$ be a non-empty subset of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that

$$\left|\bigcup_{i\in I_0}X_i\right|=\min_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[n]}\left|\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\right|\,.$$

We're told that there is a positive integer $k$ such that

$$k\cdot\min_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[n]}\left|\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\right|\le\left|\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\right|$$

for each non-empty $I\subseteq[n]$, so in particular

$$k\cdot\min_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[n]}\left|\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\right|\le\left|\bigcup_{i\in I_0}X_i\right|=\min_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[n]}\left|\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\right|\,.$$

What must $k$ be? Then remember that $\left|\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\right|\ge|I|$ for each non-empty $I\subseteq[n]$.

Comment: I'm sorry. But I don't understand how this result in $$k \cdot |I| \leq |\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i|$$ for all $I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$.

Comment: @FranciscoAntonio: Did you figure out what $k$ has to be? That follows immediately from the last displayed line and is the key to the final conclusion.

Comment: k=1. Why $I$ must be different of empty in each minimum?

Comment: @FranciscoAntonio: Let $k\in[n]$, and set $I=\{k\}$; then $\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i=X_k$, so $$|X_k|=\left|\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\right|\ge|I|=1\,.$$

Comment: Then we can assume that $$k \cdot (\min_{I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}} (|\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i|)) \leq |\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i|, \forall I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$$ is equivalent to $$k \cdot (\min_{\emptyset \neq I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}} (|\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i|)) \leq |\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i|, \forall I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$$? Why?

Comment: @FranciscoAntonio: It’s clear that non-empty sets are intended. If $\varnothing$ were allowed on the lefthand side, the inequality would be true for all $k$, and the desired conclusion would be false.